# Change rendering of a particular CharField in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model `BankAccount`. `BankAccount` model contains `CharField` `IBAN` which is a International Bank Account Number. I use `{{ bank_account.IBAN }}` in multiple templates. It's stored as a string without spaces but I want to change it's template rendering such that every 4 characters are followed by zero.

`SK121234123412341234` will be rendered as `SK12 1234 1234 1234 1234`

I could probably create some `TemplateTag` or `TemplateFilter` but I'm curious if there is a way to change it in `BankAccount` model. For example create my own `IBANField` (overriding `CharField`) so I don't have to surrounding `IBAN` variable by `tags` or `filters`.

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40, ... )
    ...
```

Didn't find rendering methods here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: What do you mean by rendering ? Do you mean after saving? Something that render in live time ?

Comment: I mean the way how {{ IBAN }} var looks like in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom field, but the easiest thing is just to write a method that displays the value in the right format. Something like:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    ..
    def display_iban(self):
        return ''.join(l + ' ' if (i+1) % 4 == 0 else l for i, l in enumerate(self.IBAN))
```

and now you can do `{{ bank_account.display_iban }}` in the template.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good idea but still, which method in custom field is responsible for how the value looks like in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry if this is off topic, but how do you decide between using a method and a property in this case?

Comment: @souldeux templates call methods automatically so there would be no difference here.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik it doesn't really work like that. Templates just display the values they're given; to customise the representation of a field you would have to change the way it was loaded from the database, probably via the [`from_db_field` or `to_python` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I understand, I thought that there is some kind of render_field function or something like that. Thanks, I will use your approach.

Comment: Rendering is done by the widget.  I would guess you would want to create a custom widget, but I have not done that myself.